# Redirect to the specified URL After the Azure SSO

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, redirect, single-sign-on

In Apache Tomcat we have hosted our web application, for this we have configurated the Microsoft Azure OAuth Single Sign-On.
After the SSO i want my application to redirect to a specified URL.
For Example : If the Specified URL is https://localhost:xxxx/test/admin/ i want it to redirect to this url after the Authentication ,but in my case it is redirecting to the home page i.e https://localhost:xxxx/. The link that is registered in the Azure portal is https://localhost:xxxx/.
I have Followed this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-security-support?tabs=SpringCloudAzure5x.
this is the controller class.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1vPD.png)
this is the SecurityConfiguration class.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpjof.png)